# Portable implementation of norm2 in fortran

Tags: fortran

It was a huge surprise for me that IBM in their implementation of the fortran 2008 standard has not provided the `norm2` function. If we have a real multidimensional array `a`, we can substitute for instance

```
norm2(a,3)
```

with

```
sqrt(sum(a**2,3))
```

In the case of complex valued array, we can write

```
sqrt(sum(Abs(a)**2,3))
```

However, there is a lot of work to implement it properly for all circumstances. I was wondering if there is a short implementation that works in all cases that fortran 2008 standard specifies.

Comment: Surprising. But note the standard requires the argument to be of type `real` so you need not consider the complex case, only all real kinds.

Comment: @IanBush That is good too know. Yet another surprise for me, this time with the standard.

Comment: You'd better interface it to the BLAS snrm2/dnrm2/scnrm2/dznrm2

Comment: @PierU I was thinking about that. Indeed this is the simplest idea, moreover that I mostly use rank-1 and 2 arrays. It is also sufficient do consider only  snrm2/dnrm2 because complex ones can be implemented in terms of these. What makes trouble, however, it the second optional argument to `norm2`. I use it sometimes.

Comment: Indeed you need wrapper routines, with an optional argument "dim="